# Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file, ftp, windows-server-2003

Windows XP this batch file/text file method will automatically ftp files to an FTP Server.
I am trying to get this to work on WIndows Server 2003 but I get an error, cannot open file.txt.  Any ideas on another method to get this working? Thanks

**batchfile contents:**

ftp -i -n -s:file.txt FTPServerIP

**file.txt contents:**

username 
user 
password 
cd import 
mput * 
quit

Comment: What is the PWD for the file.  Rather what directory are you starting in?

Comment: Is it possible that the batch files executes from a directory where there is no file.txt present? If this is the case then you could move the batch file in the correct directory or set the fullpathname in the option -s: (for example -s:c:\myuploads\file.txt)

Comment: Do you have security setup to allow access to the folder and have you tried running as admin?

Comment: There is no PWD for the file. Its not a file/folder path issue, I verified this. I created the folder that I have the batch file and text file in and have full rights. Is there another method I can use in a batch file to auto login and put files on an FTP Server? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified file name?  `ftp -i -n -s:"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Folder\file.txt" FTPServerIP`

Comment: David thanks for the reply.  Yes I did try supplying the full path. Still got the same error.

Comment: Any ideas on another method to try?  Thanks again.

Comment: Try to add these commands before the call to the ftp command: `echo %~dp0 <newline>type file.txt <newline> ftp -i -n -s:file.txt FTPServer` . This will give some hints if you are in the right directory when you execute the ftp command and if you could read the file.txt using a normal DOS command

Comment: @user1804387  I have tried it myself on Windows Server 2003 and have had no problems.  There is either a file access protection issue or cmd filesystem issue.  I recommend trying what Steve said.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond, I just got a chance to look at this again.   I created new files and it works fine now.  Not sure what it was. Thanks for everyone's help.  How to select the correct answer? Thanks again.

Comment: To answer this, create an answer in the box below, then click the check mark next to it.

Comment: @user1804387 I have tried it myself on Windows Server 2003 and have had no problems. There is either a file access protection issue or cmd filesystem issue. I recommend trying what Steve said. – David Ruhmann Dec 28 '12 at 2:34
 
Sorry I took so long to respond, I just got a chance to look at this again. I created new files and it works fine now. Not sure what it was. Thanks for everyone's help. How to select the correct answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Our new user hasn't popped his unknown solution in yet so I'll add what he typed to try and let folks know *this is solved*, though the user doesn't know what the issue was. @user1804387: when you have two minutes feel free to *post* your answer (even though you don't know what fixed it) in the empty box you see on this page called "Your Answer". Once you do, I'll be happy to delete this answer so only yours remains. Right after you do create the answer, be sure to press the checkmark symbol next to your new answer to indicate it's the correct answer. :-)

In the meantime this is *resolved* as user described:

> "I just got a chance to look at this again. I created new files and it
>   works fine now. Not sure what it was."